# Python, erro na função ao trocar valor por float

Tags: python

Se o valor digitado na compra e pagamento forem int, o código funciona, caso um único valor seja float, retorna um erro.
Meu objetivo com esse algoritmo é que ao digitar um valor de compra e um valor de pagamento, retorne a quantidade de notas e moedas especificas como troco.

Ex:

Compra: 80

Pagamento: 100

1 nota de 20 real.

Erro:

Compra: 95.35

Pagamento: 100

Expectativa:

2 nota de 2 real.

1 moeda de 0.50 centavo.

1 moeda de 0.10 centavo.

1 moeda de 0.05 centavo.

Realidade:

TypeError: '>=' not supported between instances of 'NoneType' and 'int'

A função funciona com int, mas quando digito um float retorna esse erro.

```py
def funcaoTroco(x):
    if x >= 200:
        troco.append('200')
        return total - 200
    elif x >= 100:
        troco.append('100')
        return total - 100
    elif x >= 50:
        troco.append('50')
        return total - 50
    elif x >= 20:
        troco.append('20')
        return total - 20
    elif x >= 10:
        troco.append('10')
        return total - 10
    elif x >= 5:
        troco.append('5')
        return total - 5
    elif x >= 2:
        troco.append('2')
        return total - 2
    elif x >= 1:
        troco.append('1')
        return total - 1
    elif x >= 0.50:
        troco.append('0.50')
        return total - 0.50
    elif x >= 0.25:
        troco.append('0.25')
        return total - 0.25
    elif x >= 0.10:
        troco.append('0.10')
        return total - 0.10
    elif x >= 0.05:
        troco.append('0.05')
        return total - 0.05
    elif x >= 0.01:
        troco.append('0.01')
        return total - 0.01

compra = float(input('Digite o valor total da compra:            '))
pagamento = float(input('Digite a quantia oferecida como pagamento: '))
total = float(str('%.2f' % round(pagamento - compra, 2)))
print(total)
print(type(total))
troco = []

while total != 0:
    total = funcaoTroco(total)

print('Valor de compra:    ', compra)
print('Valor do pagamento: ', pagamento)
for i in troco:
    if int(i) >= 1:
        print(f'{troco.count(i)} no valor de ', i, 'real.')
    else:
        print(f'{troco.count(i)} no valor de ', i, 'centavo.')
```

Comment: Mano, no primeiro paragrafo explique a sua duvida, coloque o seu codigo dentro de aspas para ficar visualmente melhor de te ajudar

Comment: Desculpe, fiz meio que na pressa e nem vi que a estrutura havia ficado bagunçada.

Comment: `float` não é adequado para trabalhar com valores monetários, para saber mais leia [aqui](/q/5642/112052) (e siga os links que tem nas respostas também). Enfim, uma alternativa é multiplicar por 100 para obter o valor em centavos, assim vc só lida com números inteiros, e aí vc usa um algoritmo parecido com [esse](/a/467069/112052), ficaria assim: https://ideone.com/o4tsVK

Comment: Vou seguir suas instruções @hkotsubo. Obrigado.

Answer (score 0):

Olá, estou inciando na programação. Minha soluçao:

```
def funcaoTroco(x):
    if x >= 200:
        return 200
    elif x >= 100:
        return 100
    elif x >= 50:
        return 50
    elif x >= 20:
        return 20
    elif x >= 10:
        return 10
    elif x >= 5:
        return 5
    elif x >= 2:
        return 2
    elif x >= 1:
        return 1
    elif x >= 0.50:
        return 0.50
    elif x >= 0.25:
        return 0.25
    elif x >= 0.10:
        return 0.10
    elif x >= 0.05:
        return 0.05
    elif x >= 0.01:
        return 0.01
compra = float(input('Digite o valor total da compra:            '))
pagamento = float(input('Digite a quantia oferecida como pagamento: '))
total = pagamento - compra
print(total)
print(type(total))
troco = []

if total == 0:
    print('Não há troco.')
elif total < 0:
    print('Valor insuficiente.')
else:
    while total != 0:
        troco.append(funcaoTroco(total))
        total = round(total - funcaoTroco(total), 2)
    print('Valor de compra:    ', compra)
    print('Valor do pagamento: ', pagamento)
    for i in troco:
        if int(i) >= 1:
            print(f'{troco.count(i)} no valor de ', i, 'real.')
        else:
            print(f'{troco.count(i)} no valor de ', i, 'centavo.')
```